# RDBMSLoginModule: ClassCastException com.ibm.ws.jdbc.DataSourceService to javax.sql.DataSource

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to setup a Worklight desktop app with some basic security. I have successfully used RDBMSLoginModule with a DB2 express but now that I switched to MySQL, I'm getting errors.

Here's the message I get on attempting to login to the application:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.jdbc.DataSourceService cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
```

Here's part of my setup in server.xml:

```
<dataSource id="MySQL" jdbcDriverRef="MySQLJDBCDriver" jndiName="jdbc/newapp">
    <properties databaseName="newapp" password="passw0rd" portNumber="3306" serverName="localhost" user="root"/>
</dataSource>
<library id="lib">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/mysql" includes="mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar"/>
</library>
<jdbcDriver id="MySQLJDBCDriver" libraryRef="lib"/>
```

All suggestion very much appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible you missed something else in the configuration that is still pointing to the DB2 JDBC driver? It looks like it is trying to cast com.ibm.ws.jdbc.DataSourceService over to the java jdbc standard of javax.sql.DataSource, which the MySQL driver implements.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I've checked and I don't think there is any reference to DB2 in my config. The above is all there is that I added to the server.xml. I don't think Worklight specifies which database is used by RDBMSLoginModule

Comment: Agreed because I did some quick searches yesterday and found an example that looked exactly like your above.  Maybe you can post more of the stacktrace/exception and possibly that might provide a clue.

Comment: Ok I think I solved the problem - looks like mysql jar file was not loading into Liberty properly - my file was a different version to the one I specified in the server.xml. In my defence - not a very helpful error message..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem - looks like mysql jar file was not loading into Liberty properly - my file was a different version to the one I specified in the server.xml, and therefore Liberty couldn't locate it. In my defence - not a very helpful error message..

Comment: Now give yourself credit for solving it by marking your answer as 'Accepted' - get the credit!

Comment: :) apparently I can only accept my own answer tomorrow :)